# C++ timeout function

Tags: c++, timeout, microcontroller, atmel

I want to realize a timeout function in C++ on a Atmel evaluation kit.

The program should open the function "start()" and if this function is not completed within "0.5s" it should be killed.

Are there any existing function to do jobs like this?

regard
matl

Comment: try using sleep in callee and after sleep return to caller

Comment: look at `std::async` and `std::chrono`

Comment: @AliKazmi:  sleep function requires an operating system.  Embedded systems may not have an OS.

Comment: @OMGtechy std:chrono give me the timeperiode of a function, but if it is hanging in the function because of for example big calculations or an error I am not able to kill the function because I will get the result too late.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: `std::future::wait_for`. You get either `future_status::ready` or `future_status::timeout`.

Comment: This is possible only in C++11 (-std=c++11 or -std=c++0x depending on compiler). On C++03 you have to use OS calls (if one) or implement it via interrupt

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: Of course. But the question wasn't tagged C++03 or C++14, so the reasonable assumption is C++ as it's defined today.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, these kinds of functions are always hand-crafted because in embedded systems, the target system is not standardized.

You could purchase an OS and use methods like messaging timeouts and sleeping.

Without an OS, you have to craft the functionality yourself using a timer and the timer interrupt (ISR).

Comment: Are there any suggetions how to create a timeout with timer and timer interrupt? At the moment I do not know how to realize something like this. If the program is hanging in the function start() how can I access the timer data? Maybe it is just a  error in reasoning but I do not get it now.

Comment: @matl It's very specific to the hw. You have to refer to the libraries given with the enviorment